# Seeing error bash: mvn: command not found and getting this error Failed to collect dependencies at io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:jar:5.6.3:

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, dependencies, maven-3

So, i was trying to add bonigarcia maven dependency to my intellij project here my selenium version is 3.14. Bonigarcia dependency which i am trying to add is

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

While adding this dependancy version number is showing in red.

So, thought of running this command mvn clean install -U, but while running this cmd it shows mvn cmd not found. Prior running this cmd, i also tried build and compile, but didn't help.
Though i am able to see other dependancies of maven in my project and when i am trying to run a basic script of opening google and closing i am able to. I am trying these to create a base class with webdriver, but i am getting these error. Attach a sample screenshot of my project what i am trying to [Intellij project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PERT.jpg) . What should i do to solve these error.
P.S : I further verified the version 5.6.3 is compatible with selenium 3 so that should not be an issue.

Basic script sample which worked for me

```
package Test;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class SampleClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/x/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-       arm64/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: `mvn` is only available if you installed maven for the command line for your system.  I would strongly recommend getting that to work first